# How can I select an element with multiple child elements all of which having attributes not equal to a specific value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<Audit>
    <Clsinfo>

        <Class Discipline="BUSA" Number="7" Credits="4" Letter_grade="A" Id_num="0043">
            <Attribute Code="DWSISKEY" Value="1-1-1"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="CSB4"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="N"/>
        </Class>

        <Class Discipline="BUSA" Number="72" Credits="5" Letter_grade="A" Id_num="0025">
            <Attribute Code="DWSISKEY" Value="21173"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="CSB4"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="N"/>
        </Class>

        <Class Discipline="BSKI" Number="8" Credits="4" Letter_grade="A" Id_num="0051">
            <Attribute Code="DWSISKEY" Value="1-1-2"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="P"/>
        </Class>

        <Class Discipline="CHIN" Number="1" Credits="4" Letter_grade="A" Id_num="0019">
            <Attribute Code="DWSISKEY" Value="72800"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="AAC2"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="ASC2"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="CSC2"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="IG6A"/>
            <Attribute Code="ATTRIBUTE" Value="N"/>
        </Class>

    </Clsinfo>

    <Fallthrough Classes="4" Credits="21" Noncourses="0">
        <Class Discipline="BUSA" Number="72" Credits="5" Letter_grade="A" Id_num="0025"/>
        <Class Discipline="BSKI" Number="8" Credits="4" Letter_grade="P" Id_num="0051"/>
        <Class Discipline="CHIN" Number="1" Credits="4" Letter_grade="A" Id_num="0019"/>
    </Fallthrough>
</Audit>
```

I would like to split the Fallthrough classes into 2 groups called Basic Skills and Others.  The Basic Skills group has classes in the Fallthrough which links to the Class Element through the Id_num, and one of the attributes of the linked Class element has a value of "P".  Otherwise, if none of the attributes of the linked Class element has a value of "P", it'll be displayed in the Others group.

So, with my xml, i would like to have this output:

Basic Skills

BSKI 8

Others

BUSA 72
CHIN 1

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me on this.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: In what format is the expected output: text, html or...?

Comment: Can you post the desired output and what you've tried so far?

Comment: The expected output in TEXT is fine.  It should be like this:
Basic Skills

BSKI 8 

Others

BUSA 72 CHIN 1

I've tried to for each on Fallthrough and do another for each loop on ClsInfo/Class, and was able to built the list for Basic Skills; however, I couldn't do it with the OTHERS as I couldn't find a way to store the value to a variable more than once as I went through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:key name="ftclass" match="Fallthrough/Class" use="@Id_num" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Basic Skills:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Audit/Clsinfo/Class[key('ftclass', @Id_num)/@Letter_grade='P']" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;Others:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Audit/Clsinfo/Class[not(key('ftclass', @Id_num)/@Letter_grade='P')]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Discipline" />
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Number" />
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the provided input, the (text) output is:

```
Basic Skills:
BSKI 8
Others:
BUSA 7, BUSA 72, CHIN 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Michael!  However, this is not the correct output.  I made a mistake in my original post that the OTHERS contain BUSA7.  It should not.  However, your code was based on the Letter Grade, whereas it should base on the ATTRIBUTE instead.

Comment: @user3300090 It sounds like you want the same thing, except in the opposite direction. Can't you do the reversal yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Find updated one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:key name="ftclass" match="Fallthrough/Class" use="@Id_num"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Basic Skills:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates  select="Audit/Clsinfo/Class[key('ftclass', @Id_num)][Attribute/attribute::*='P']"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;Others:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Audit/Clsinfo/Class[key('ftclass', @Id_num)][not(Attribute/attribute::*='P')]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Class">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Discipline"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
      <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Basic Skills:
BSKI 8
Others:
BUSA 72, CHIN 1
```

Comment: Navin,  Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, it's not the correct output.  the OTHERs should not contain BSKI 8, and it should also NOT contain BUSA 7 (It was my mistake in my original post that BUSA 7 was in the output) .  The logic should go like this: for each class in Fallthrough, get the Id_num; look that up in the ClsInfo/Class that has the same Id_num.  Then look for the list of Attributes of that matched Class to see if any attribute is equal to "P".  If so, put it in the Basic Skill; otherwise, if none of the attributes is equals to P, put it in the OTHERS section.